# How do I create a bash script that will list all private repos on github using OAUTH token?

Tags: git, github, oauth

On github, I generated an OAUTH token.

I am not sure how to use this, as there are no examples given with what I want to do, and the other simple examples do not work.

I want to simply list all private repos (one repo per line), that's it.

---

If anyone has done this in a bash script, please post.  I am on RHEL 8.2, minimally I can use bash and perl in the script.

I want to keep it super simple and have it work on a system by default (with what is there by default) without installing additional packages (like other languages to parse the JSON response).

I have perl code that will parse out the repos from the JSON response (for public repos), but not sure how to fetch private repos using OAUTH token.  Perl because it's there by default when I install RHEL 8.2 (if I can leave this out and do in pure bash, or some other GNU util found on every install by default, would do that also).

---

I want the script to get all private repos, not just the first page, so it would need to work some magic to go beyond what you would see with web page pagination.

I will post the final solution, once I piece that together.

Comment: Do you want to list all private repos to which you have access, or all private repos in an organization, or just every private repo on GitHub, regardless of whether you're allowed to view it?

Comment: I only want to list private repos that I have access to via my account, whether that is in an organization I have access to, or just a private repo that I created.  I don't want to list private repos for which I don't have access.

Comment: I think you'll need to iterate over all the organizations you have access to and fetch their private repositories individually and then iterate over your own.